# use of controllers with Blazor Assembly service

Tags: controller, blazor

The sample solution has for FetchData.Razor
forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
The quoted part Seems to indicate the name of the controller. Is that correct ?

I want to extend the example to understand how to use it. To do this I would enable the user to choose a refresh rate and automatically refresh the data  - but first step
is to record the 2 values with a new class LastUpdateInfo in .shared weatherForcast.cs

```
public class LastUpDateInfo
    {
        public int updateRateSecs { get; set; }
        public DateTime RefreshDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

While the solution does compile, I get an unhandled exception -response status code does not indicate success. (500)

I added this to controller

```
   public LastUpDateInfo GetUpdateInfo()
        {
            var thisUpDateInfo = new LastUpDateInfo();
            thisUpDateInfo.RefreshDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            thisUpDateInfo.updateRateSecs = 3;  // needs to be fed from UX
            return thisUpDateInfo;

        }
```

and called  from FetchData.razor

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        currInfo = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<LastUpDateInfo>("WeatherForecast");
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast"); // URI ? is the quoted the controllerName ?
        // why is there a literal here called "WeatherForecast" ??
    }
```

The blazor assembly feels quite different than previous Rest API with razor pages (cshtml) and Im struggling to get a grasp of the mechanics.

Thanks !

I added a second class, updated the controller and called from FetchData.razor
However the call throws an error ( 500 ) but dont understand how it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Client/Program.cs` you can find a line like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

This registers an `HttpClient` as a scoped service. The `BaseAddress` of the `HttpClient` is configured to be the address of the "host environment". The host is basically the Server application where the api also exists. Let's say your server is listening on `https://localhost:3377` so this is the `BaseAddress` of the `HttpClient`.

When you call:

```
await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
```

the string parameter is the relative uri that should be appended to the base address, in this case "WeatherForecast". The final uri will be base address uri + relative uri so it will send a GET request to `https://localhost:3377/WeatherForecast`.

This is the route for the `Get` endpoint in the `WeatherForecastController`. This happens because the controller has the `[Route("[controller]")]` attribute. This means all the endpoints inside this controller will start with `/WeatherForecast` in the route. The `Get` method does not have its own `Route` attribute so the final route to access it is `https://localhost:3377/WeatherForecast`.

On your `GetUpdateInfo` method you also did not specify a route so both endpoints have the same route and the app can't differentiate between the two so it throws exception. Instead in your `GetUpdateInfo` endpoint you can add a `[Route("UpdateInfo")]` attribute.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("UpdateInfo")]
public LastUpDateInfo GetUpdateInfo()
{
    var thisUpDateInfo = new LastUpDateInfo();
    thisUpDateInfo.RefreshDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    thisUpDateInfo.updateRateSecs = 3;  // needs to be fed from UX
    return thisUpDateInfo;
}
```

Then the absolute route to that endpoint will be `https://localhost:3377/WeatherForecast/UpdateInfo` and in your Client you can do:

```
await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<LastUpDateInfo>("WeatherForecast/UpdateInfo");
```

You can check [Attribute routing for REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) to better understand how routing in ASP.NET Core controllers works.